# in Android How to change list item color and stores it even after closing it

Tags: java, android, list, sharedpreferences

```
            final String[] choice = {"Edit","Completed"};
            builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(todo_home.this);
            builder.setTitle("SELECT:");
            builder.setItems(choice, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    if ("Completed".equals(choice[which])){
                        listView.getChildAt(idd).setBackgroundColor(Color.CYAN);
                        todo_home.arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("com.example.todo_notes", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                        HashSet<String> set = new HashSet<>(notes);
                        sharedPreferences.edit().putStringSet("notes", set).apply();

                        Log.v("Selected item", (String) listView.getItemAtPosition(idd)+ "**&&****&**&** " +notes.get(idd));
                    }
```

I tried to use shared preferences to store the changed color but it was not working.

Comment: The question and the code snippet is unclear.

Comment: Hi Daniel, I want to know that in Android How to change list item color when we click on some item of the list. And when we close the app and open the app again changes should have present.

Comment: do you mean listview or recyclerview or AlertDialog's list?

Comment: Hello, Hamed I meant list view here.

Comment: How is the code snippet related to your question? Also, what do you mean by"after closing"? You should use savedInstanceState if it's temporary, or sharedPreferences or roomDatabase for persistent.

Comment: Hello Daniel, I want to use shared Preferences but I am able to use shared preferences only on the content of lists , not on the color of the list item.